# Htaccess – remove html extension + add trailing slash + find index inside subfolder (combined)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

I've been struggling with this question for a week now.

My website root is something like this:

```
index.html
page.html
subfolder/index.html
subfolder/page.html
```

I've read tons of posts to do these 3 things. I can actually do them separately but I can't figure how to do them combined!

1. Remove the `.html` extension
2. Automatically look for `index.html` inside a subfolder
3. Add a slash on the end of the `URL` (i.e. `www.domain.com/subfolder/page.html` to `www.domain.com/subfolder/page/`

It would be super if while writing `www.domain.com/page.html` the `URL` would automatically change to `www.domain.com/page/`

Thank you in advance!

**My htaccess at the moment:**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all of your code block with this one:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on

# redirect file.html to /file/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,NE,L]

# added .html extension to /file by checking presence of file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```